# Calculate overlap ellipses regions in R

Tags: r, plot, overlap, ellipse

I have two datasets with ellipses centroids coordinates (X & Y), Areas, Major and Minor axes (and other variables).  My aim is to calculate the overlap between the groups of ellipses and plot them.

The main question is regarding calculations of overlapping regions.
For plotting I would use draw.ellipse function but I'm open to other alternatives.

The two datasets are very similar, here's a subset of one of the two datasets.

```
dput(slide0[,2:5])
structure(list(Area = c(15453600L, 89L, 151L, 80L, 72L, 126L, 
228L, 140L, 192L, 180L, 226L, 96L, 128L, 214L, 176L, 102L, 180L, 
229L, 326L, 148L, 86L, 151L, 148L, 255L, 102L, 226L, 224L, 207L, 
136L, 115L, 133L, 199L, 124L, 268L, 172L, 207L, 128L, 216L, 136L, 
292L, 232L, 79L, 107L, 190L, 104L, 190L, 226L, 136L, 102L, 148L, 
130L, 138L, 180L, 200L, 130L, 177L, 183L, 164L, 140L, 292L, 180L, 
161L, 79L, 161L, 80L, 207L, 140L, 151L, 190L, 112L, 208L, 207L, 
293L, 146L, 116L, 364L, 238L, 154L, 400L, 190L, 208L, 240L, 158L, 
98L, 107L, 133L, 217L, 86L, 112L, 86L, 96L, 138L, 224L, 220L, 
102L, 154L, 200L, 158L, 190L, 375L, 281L, 604L, 304L, 346L, 186L, 
320L, 454L, 200L, 194L, 281L, 247L, 176L, 148L, 252L, 88L, 208L, 
236L, 268L, 238L, 262L, 130L, 130L, 160L, 164L, 186L, 186L, 424L, 
364L, 192L, 136L, 247L, 148L, 214L, 236L, 560L, 376L, 104L, 180L, 
300L, 70L, 343L, 420L, 389L, 84L, 248L, 314L, 302L, 144L, 60L, 
88L, 107L, 95L, 116L, 89L, 62L, 124L, 115L, 72L, 140L, 330L, 
762L, 931L, 390L, 298L, 256L, 288L, 52L, 48L, 122L, 247L, 88L, 
299L, 324L, 96L, 121L, 52L, 70L, 97L, 758L, 112L, 234L, 147L, 
75L, 80L, 96L, 84L, 97L, 36L, 44L, 79L, 40L, 121L, 48L, 79L, 
54L, 52L, 61L, 52L, 89L, 92L, 200L, 60L, 156L, 64L, 72L, 200L, 
48L, 44L, 136L, 136L, 112L, 84L, 98L, 84L, 58L, 42L, 48L, 70L, 
54L, 104L, 75L, 80L, 88L, 37L, 95L, 160L, 79L, 137L, 138L, 172L, 
80L, 32L, 148L, 314L, 180L, 236L, 234L, 72L, 124L, 121L, 164L, 
255L, 207L, 122L, 414L, 254L, 85L, 133L, 80L, 151L, 102L, 61L, 
147L, 220L, 192L, 340L, 200L, 133L, 164L, 136L, 136L, 140L, 281L, 
208L, 400L, 112L, 96L, 240L, 234L, 136L, 80L, 177L, 130L, 207L, 
121L, 248L, 104L, 88L, 192L, 200L, 359L, 276L, 84L, 96L, 177L, 
214L, 104L, 92L, 102L, 147L, 136L, 208L, 281L, 112L, 151L, 146L, 
161L, 96L, 21L, 44L, 82L, 124L, 92L, 64L, 84L, 97L, 98L, 16L, 
60L, 115L, 126L, 60L, 75L, 80L, 86L, 84L, 89L, 96L, 82L, 72L, 
200L, 80L, 70L, 79L, 80L, 177L, 44L, 79L, 122L, 75L, 104L, 84L, 
158L, 139L, 146L, 69L, 281L, 448L, 68L, 170L, 115L, 236L, 244L, 
97L, 104L, 84L, 70L, 70L, 96L, 68L, 96L, 70L, 89L, 380L, 44L, 
122L, 320L, 556L, 140L, 208L, 288L, 225L, 302L, 304L, 180L, 210L, 
160L, 194L, 151L, 172L, 320L, 256L, 208L, 341L, 346L, 107L, 98L, 
51L, 79L, 292L, 229L, 192L, 484L, 176L, 146L, 115L, 89L, 69L, 
151L, 72L, 651L, 512L, 384L, 124L, 128L, 82L, 128L, 124L, 121L, 
72L, 398L, 190L, 354L, 182L, 228L, 531L, 354L, 236L, 298L, 238L, 
638L, 400L, 247L, 166L, 210L, 156L, 224L, 264L, 89L, 228L, 254L, 
181L, 247L, 200L, 310L, 238L, 177L, 144L, 133L, 340L, 311L, 146L, 
322L, 220L, 190L, 398L, 166L, 228L, 161L, 137L, 128L, 86L, 104L, 
42L, 116L, 60L, 192L, 398L, 264L, 255L, 447L, 244L, 324L, 182L, 
247L, 383L, 292L, 484L, 760L, 550L, 740L, 884L, 414L, 400L, 344L, 
416L, 380L, 476L, 298L, 154L, 82L, 199L, 767L, 228L, 420L, 238L, 
146L, 176L, 326L, 273L, 126L, 104L, 166L, 266L, 226L, 76L, 133L, 
256L, 136L, 61L, 314L, 144L, 260L, 200L, 147L, 356L, 540L, 239L, 
200L, 186L, 217L, 69L, 208L, 346L, 382L, 207L, 300L, 140L, 161L, 
398L, 176L, 228L, 112L, 160L, 266L, 190L, 254L, 84L, 732L, 224L, 
532L, 244L, 384L, 255L, 369L, 432L, 216L, 288L, 236L, 207L, 302L, 
232L, 151L, 86L, 124L, 44L, 128L, 124L, 292L, 102L, 144L, 92L, 
225L, 293L, 266L, 549L, 284L, 144L, 254L, 136L, 186L, 180L, 164L, 
166L, 146L, 200L, 236L, 186L, 148L, 154L, 226L, 158L, 140L, 160L, 
136L, 102L, 341L, 253L, 121L, 121L, 340L, 224L, 148L, 216L, 220L, 
366L, 188L, 154L, 228L, 236L, 208L, 240L, 324L, 172L, 302L, 164L, 
420L, 254L, 88L, 224L, 210L, 124L, 264L, 315L, 332L, 190L, 128L, 
130L, 220L, 166L, 107L, 112L, 158L, 116L, 98L, 147L, 192L, 186L, 
112L, 210L, 84L, 256L, 274L, 200L, 192L, 192L, 170L, 107L, 302L, 
244L, 299L, 170L, 115L, 186L, 208L, 156L, 216L, 220L, 332L, 451L, 
340L, 210L, 128L, 176L, 456L, 128L, 495L, 194L, 316L, 236L, 199L, 
870L, 248L, 172L, 192L, 240L, 200L, 192L, 208L, 126L, 344L, 384L, 
420L, 176L, 167L, 128L, 86L, 151L, 96L, 104L, 200L, 208L, 72L, 
176L, 116L, 192L, 79L, 96L, 328L, 568L, 302L, 229L, 130L, 354L, 
89L, 84L, 112L, 160L, 92L, 217L, 341L, 240L, 369L, 268L, 136L, 
324L, 192L, 326L, 89L, 146L, 158L, 194L, 214L, 161L, 96L, 172L, 
136L, 172L, 240L, 180L, 108L, 524L, 102L, 138L, 166L, 146L, 177L, 
137L, 140L, 140L, 274L, 576L, 264L, 86L, 225L, 396L, 239L, 434L, 
782L, 322L, 112L, 80L, 200L, 136L, 144L, 238L, 96L, 130L, 86L, 
102L, 92L, 356L, 255L, 264L, 288L, 140L, 299L, 264L, 299L, 186L, 
146L, 383L, 214L, 375L, 186L, 273L, 284L, 122L, 284L, 72L, 79L, 
292L, 192L, 396L, 276L, 228L, 260L, 172L, 172L, 107L, 80L, 104L, 
98L, 186L, 226L, 104L, 180L, 85L, 144L, 120L, 248L, 315L, 151L, 
166L, 236L, 136L, 540L, 341L, 200L, 226L, 208L, 112L, 160L, 96L, 
260L, 262L, 130L, 177L, 116L, 98L, 112L, 208L, 239L, 176L, 151L, 
186L, 130L, 177L, 172L, 122L, 183L, 133L, 248L, 146L, 217L, 746L, 
199L, 224L, 225L, 140L, 172L, 244L, 274L, 158L, 136L, 344L, 172L, 
82L, 200L, 70L, 95L, 239L, 176L, 180L, 147L, 116L, 89L, 79L, 
89L, 112L, 240L, 200L, 326L, 84L, 264L, 266L, 266L, 262L, 247L, 
164L, 217L, 210L, 122L, 214L, 316L, 217L, 364L, 192L, 660L, 764L, 
584L, 228L, 498L, 314L, 188L, 130L, 166L, 255L, 477L, 200L, 816L, 
176L, 247L, 252L, 126L, 100L), Mean = c(175.038, 100.18, 99.781, 
116.9, 108.375, 94.373, 105.987, 102.993, 90.74, 114.856, 99.412, 
123.5, 99.008, 146.168, 88.818, 99.814, 87.244, 68.223, 86.868, 
96.189, 133.523, 119.159, 137.311, 109.8, 102.98, 95.407, 112.612, 
106.957, 147.382, 76.904, 101.774, 67.02, 118.984, 85.851, 77.355, 
91.894, 91.773, 67.833, 103.397, 110.363, 124.513, 112.595, 123.794, 
87.847, 88.058, 102.268, 105.354, 89.184, 141.618, 151.291, 135.746, 
86.283, 87.389, 102.32, 106.592, 90.153, 100.055, 84.701, 93.264, 
97.586, 99.317, 88.05, 94.038, 99.665, 89.763, 100.072, 82.714, 
116.325, 102.879, 102.911, 90.317, 92.217, 99.594, 72.425, 91.336, 
90.514, 96.197, 103.89, 106.513, 103.647, 98.216, 98.338, 122.513, 
104.49, 114.467, 121.278, 109.327, 97.616, 93.223, 98.767, 132.302, 
91.964, 86.58, 85.559, 98.5, 90.643, 87.21, 79.715, 90.995, 73.584, 
96.153, 118.086, 112.441, 118.208, 115.199, 143.731, 132.555, 
128.76, 79.83, 106.466, 83.142, 88.091, 94.243, 110.254, 118.489, 
97.24, 74.771, 117, 89.706, 96.08, 93.846, 105.515, 102.225, 
120.75, 97.828, 109.059, 102.245, 106.357, 97.891, 114.566, 92.344, 
100.858, 130.467, 114.619, 133.125, 147.027, 95.673, 108.178, 
104.57, 108.214, 123.924, 110.233, 115.861, 124.905, 106.996, 
81.987, 93.914, 111.611, 118.7, 138.432, 150.972, 156.842, 163.371, 
102.764, 141.629, 136.694, 163.287, 133.194, 104.5, 113.645, 
149.705, 127.354, 91.405, 152.614, 148.102, 148.295, 151.462, 
175.646, 148.139, 153.636, 159.909, 173.027, 131.5, 167.656, 
176.066, 147.385, 108.643, 139.732, 105.799, 130.384, 131.346, 
115.776, 110.573, 124.5, 126.167, 157.393, 107.66, 104.5, 113.75, 
114.354, 97.825, 115.091, 104.521, 91.316, 103.056, 97.788, 118.361, 
126.5, 114.629, 130.413, 120.07, 119.083, 139.359, 117.75, 99.583, 
92.68, 128.667, 112.727, 105.206, 115.838, 112.946, 81.69, 139.439, 
120.131, 152.517, 140.024, 165.854, 147.943, 137.944, 149.625, 
154.4, 139.625, 135.58, 169.405, 97.253, 104.8, 109.215, 97.299, 
117.406, 110.953, 107.138, 125.938, 72.791, 142.236, 121.117, 
127.542, 118.175, 128.278, 132.556, 127.116, 132.098, 120.69, 
140.57, 114.943, 142.087, 136.551, 153.835, 157.098, 159.688, 
91.841, 119, 122.82, 135.707, 125.764, 115.781, 112.762, 139.22, 
126.759, 125.378, 116.353, 122.706, 123.086, 90.249, 101.139, 
128.018, 71.812, 83.365, 101.421, 108.568, 113.36, 120.787, 136.712, 
136.908, 118.826, 96.091, 65.258, 80.337, 81.307, 99.708, 79.43, 
110.613, 133.293, 119.548, 120.531, 145.672, 152.551, 112.212, 
99.511, 174.431, 124.639, 96.213, 96.519, 73.313, 95.089, 107.768, 
83.267, 61.609, 75.427, 71.286, 71.432, 46.537, 45.476, 43.022, 
62.453, 57.119, 70.371, 51.357, 61.375, 83.333, 82.426, 79.96, 
116.067, 105.707, 87.325, 112.895, 109.095, 117.281, 111.854, 
148.683, 133.125, 104.845, 127.963, 137.671, 138.911, 140.825, 
81.808, 96.727, 105.228, 97.221, 111.427, 132.558, 128.643, 81.949, 
80.36, 92.705, 118.899, 144.306, 74.203, 143.779, 101.706, 97.2, 
112.246, 128.369, 138.031, 120.625, 89.94, 106.357, 128.086, 
123.375, 131.397, 150.083, 132.829, 145.618, 91.547, 116.659, 
106.016, 112.1, 130.752, 116.714, 109.788, 123.153, 88.089, 87.811, 
76.714, 105.028, 116.762, 110.763, 86.912, 124.126, 113.262, 
100.559, 82.238, 100.933, 84.739, 88.28, 103.925, 123.255, 131.902, 
101.19, 91.973, 133.035, 145.464, 138.7, 114.074, 141.062, 149.383, 
153.36, 154.899, 157.742, 150.806, 136.886, 148.42, 161.966, 
128.024, 154.977, 156.037, 183.664, 134.484, 143.471, 174.431, 
112.766, 84.021, 109.633, 102.055, 122.228, 119.169, 126.669, 
92.72, 84.557, 109.622, 115.52, 98.305, 100.016, 86.705, 88.524, 
93.91, 121.433, 115.186, 138.775, 112.171, 139.945, 111.459, 
137.648, 148.56, 151.7, 147.475, 130.412, 150.611, 144.699, 124.879, 
127.666, 133.582, 128.419, 113.841, 143.732, 129.874, 147.084, 
125.908, 98.857, 128.482, 135.695, 98.767, 94.26, 96.024, 68.207, 
96.417, 122.438, 122.296, 105.178, 113.808, 123.345, 120.631, 
77.151, 102.319, 118.283, 111.146, 103.658, 117.19, 119.658, 
131.902, 141.754, 136.67, 130.594, 123.112, 99.02, 128.873, 143.095, 
92.819, 113.151, 127.487, 113.512, 121.085, 147.4, 142.526, 151.355, 
134.403, 146.5, 138.858, 155.043, 132.473, 126.667, 68.433, 70.066, 
147.763, 146.615, 128.263, 130.767, 121.531, 125.728, 159.721, 
132.185, 106.326, 162.808, 150.12, 133, 153.806, 138.598, 138.126, 
120.59, 121.269, 139.493, 152.304, 71.971, 82.636, 98.034, 82.251, 
102.697, 122.014, 97.708, 75.286, 52.676, 98.066, 94.866, 95.919, 
82.12, 109.942, 91.606, 86.238, 125.225, 105.902, 119.013, 126.057, 
124.857, 109.714, 120.282, 149.981, 81.801, 70.83, 142.661, 149.28, 
139.454, 137.897, 119.04, 140.558, 148.685, 140.614, 164.547, 
149.968, 136.695, 153.167, 171.521, 148.609, 151.662, 140.758, 
139.857, 138.801, 116.912, 97.34, 61.571, 80.522, 88.731, 98.472, 
74.622, 69.777, 82.164, 103.745, 99.347, 93.855, 102.203, 94.188, 
98.527, 68.627, 63.579, 70.838, 87.632, 102.745, 92.405, 88.791, 
70.331, 92.744, 106.656, 79.491, 61.176, 78.644, 98.818, 87.208, 
98.686, 91.403, 75.044, 94.814, 87.394, 102.771, 90.769, 80.698, 
58.295, 94.543, 81.545, 82.067, 95.034, 85.513, 89.924, 98.911, 
68.598, 95.787, 71.672, 76.026, 79.773, 87.8, 71.2, 95.482, 87.57, 
119.214, 77.196, 75.767, 62.02, 76.571, 89.089, 79.957, 75.821, 
80.648, 85.476, 93.469, 78.106, 82.495, 83.729, 95.271, 85.641, 
89.673, 86.904, 74.656, 105.274, 91.341, 106.678, 118.634, 100.529, 
62.436, 72.042, 110.141, 78.265, 66.938, 87.006, 73.267, 94.289, 
87.381, 97.522, 83.391, 147.455, 76.407, 94.759, 112.042, 104.347, 
122.056, 104.762, 129.169, 125.432, 120.088, 84.685, 94.495, 
92.923, 128.421, 120.352, 118.516, 106.805, 92.767, 98.958, 109.758, 
121.721, 103.106, 123.208, 134.923, 69.045, 78.149, 60.458, 161.341, 
174.319, 140.344, 157.43, 145.615, 66.009, 105.366, 112.884, 
81.873, 109.462, 124.463, 106.618, 92.798, 111.902, 109.031, 
110.728, 122.747, 146.079, 95.329, 71.645, 71.396, 105.551, 125.577, 
108.667, 96.525, 129.236, 112.384, 108.867, 124.959, 115.832, 
84.398, 109.375, 86.628, 106.676, 118.657, 113.338, 120.794, 
127.88, 133.464, 98.284, 114.703, 92.94, 102.952, 107.424, 99.102, 
81.107, 110.479, 137.737, 163.38, 151.75, 152.721, 133.849, 139.288, 
117.071, 150.302, 142.243, 131.826, 127.75, 114.162, 118.68, 
118.971, 102.493, 130.689, 159.573, 169.638, 178.302, 166.951, 
156.924, 101.371, 108.549, 91.515, 93.934, 110.864, 111.93, 131.61, 
109.916, 105.618, 116.5, 101.277, 114.187, 119.904, 105.36, 127.161, 
154.102, 60.025, 49.68, 136.403, 138.291, 61.87, 94.677, 95.404, 
98.725, 98.675, 93.288, 88.75, 78.517, 67.692, 90.513, 97.99, 
88.561, 90.403, 80.934, 81.885, 97.8, 86.376, 85.306, 75.233, 
111.649, 118.692, 103.755, 91.964, 98.381, 117.338, 164.294, 
86.323, 58.865, 66.819, 116.067, 121.83, 127.481, 134.677, 112.538, 
96.477, 98.662, 96.006, 81.853, 97.816, 106.143, 89.558, 114.297, 
139.307, 134.272, 130.72, 130.2, 88.085, 108.413, 142.852, 133.355, 
121.06, 89.391, 95.952, 96.659, 133.213, 125, 100.683, 92.884, 
106.593, 107.779, 99.766, 103.653, 62.968, 116.287, 126.256, 
135.006, 128.476, 132.255, 124.1, 149.011, 127.481, 136.932, 
144.322, 113.102, 129.422, 122.393, 115.367, 111.584, 144.991, 
116.725, 147.935, 135.571, 137.036, 171.311, 129.237, 128.368, 
144.16, 115.514, 123.665, 129.138, 145.752, 118.607, 129.668, 
113.674, 117.143, 108.503, 96.714, 137.52, 107.203, 111.435, 
90.057, 119.367, 110.799, 101.931, 113.069, 120.825, 119.478, 
106.346, 118.9, 161.491, 102.136, 93.389, 102.111, 96.429, 120.19
), Min = c(25L, 85L, 88L, 103L, 99L, 77L, 70L, 70L, 68L, 95L, 
75L, 109L, 77L, 117L, 69L, 87L, 65L, 47L, 47L, 72L, 112L, 95L, 
117L, 77L, 85L, 68L, 94L, 83L, 130L, 58L, 83L, 49L, 92L, 53L, 
57L, 72L, 72L, 49L, 83L, 86L, 102L, 93L, 112L, 76L, 69L, 89L, 
77L, 69L, 128L, 131L, 117L, 65L, 67L, 72L, 86L, 67L, 78L, 64L, 
73L, 78L, 82L, 56L, 77L, 79L, 71L, 81L, 57L, 92L, 71L, 87L, 70L, 
73L, 72L, 58L, 71L, 57L, 68L, 90L, 72L, 79L, 77L, 64L, 96L, 90L, 
100L, 101L, 88L, 77L, 70L, 85L, 106L, 72L, 63L, 66L, 76L, 72L, 
71L, 57L, 67L, 46L, 56L, 78L, 82L, 80L, 87L, 111L, 100L, 107L, 
54L, 84L, 51L, 62L, 74L, 85L, 88L, 68L, 50L, 80L, 58L, 66L, 74L, 
84L, 83L, 105L, 80L, 86L, 62L, 57L, 68L, 89L, 56L, 78L, 90L, 
85L, 103L, 116L, 80L, 85L, 85L, 94L, 84L, 88L, 78L, 102L, 85L, 
64L, 58L, 90L, 100L, 112L, 126L, 127L, 134L, 83L, 120L, 117L, 
131L, 119L, 80L, 78L, 109L, 84L, 73L, 116L, 116L, 122L, 130L, 
149L, 110L, 136L, 130L, 126L, 104L, 134L, 151L, 128L, 95L, 114L, 
84L, 108L, 92L, 90L, 90L, 107L, 98L, 124L, 84L, 88L, 103L, 89L, 
87L, 87L, 90L, 74L, 85L, 85L, 99L, 109L, 99L, 107L, 95L, 102L, 
108L, 98L, 83L, 61L, 110L, 98L, 79L, 93L, 94L, 62L, 111L, 96L, 
126L, 119L, 154L, 123L, 123L, 122L, 129L, 107L, 113L, 138L, 76L, 
84L, 90L, 80L, 93L, 93L, 90L, 109L, 55L, 105L, 94L, 99L, 95L, 
107L, 103L, 107L, 107L, 75L, 99L, 95L, 113L, 112L, 130L, 122L, 
135L, 65L, 79L, 104L, 87L, 94L, 71L, 85L, 113L, 106L, 103L, 80L, 
85L, 97L, 58L, 76L, 98L, 50L, 65L, 72L, 81L, 88L, 106L, 107L, 
99L, 85L, 77L, 46L, 60L, 61L, 80L, 59L, 78L, 83L, 96L, 100L, 
109L, 119L, 85L, 77L, 131L, 77L, 67L, 65L, 50L, 72L, 74L, 56L, 
45L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 53L, 50L, 57L, 43L, 56L, 66L, 
62L, 64L, 91L, 90L, 73L, 93L, 82L, 89L, 81L, 121L, 104L, 69L, 
107L, 118L, 111L, 120L, 65L, 78L, 87L, 77L, 96L, 98L, 108L, 64L, 
69L, 75L, 107L, 98L, 42L, 132L, 75L, 62L, 62L, 101L, 110L, 106L, 
76L, 96L, 97L, 92L, 94L, 123L, 105L, 122L, 62L, 87L, 87L, 82L, 
94L, 101L, 90L, 97L, 68L, 44L, 56L, 82L, 74L, 86L, 66L, 105L, 
87L, 67L, 59L, 70L, 58L, 54L, 77L, 104L, 98L, 85L, 65L, 96L, 
89L, 87L, 95L, 101L, 123L, 117L, 136L, 106L, 128L, 90L, 117L, 
104L, 91L, 132L, 132L, 140L, 100L, 108L, 129L, 61L, 64L, 67L, 
80L, 91L, 80L, 75L, 63L, 61L, 85L, 67L, 67L, 73L, 69L, 59L, 70L, 
105L, 88L, 114L, 72L, 112L, 79L, 104L, 129L, 112L, 120L, 95L, 
119L, 122L, 92L, 104L, 113L, 103L, 82L, 106L, 98L, 125L, 83L, 
63L, 100L, 107L, 83L, 63L, 73L, 53L, 73L, 98L, 91L, 84L, 88L, 
81L, 86L, 54L, 80L, 84L, 82L, 53L, 81L, 68L, 85L, 88L, 84L, 87L, 
80L, 80L, 92L, 99L, 58L, 80L, 89L, 88L, 89L, 94L, 100L, 113L, 
110L, 103L, 113L, 122L, 114L, 95L, 59L, 56L, 114L, 117L, 110L, 
112L, 92L, 103L, 131L, 100L, 85L, 118L, 116L, 109L, 129L, 102L, 
121L, 98L, 92L, 108L, 132L, 50L, 48L, 64L, 52L, 58L, 86L, 71L, 
49L, 42L, 67L, 80L, 68L, 55L, 69L, 70L, 62L, 96L, 81L, 75L, 79L, 
86L, 77L, 77L, 90L, 59L, 47L, 90L, 116L, 102L, 97L, 101L, 112L, 
114L, 131L, 132L, 115L, 99L, 102L, 136L, 114L, 126L, 106L, 108L, 
93L, 88L, 72L, 46L, 66L, 56L, 75L, 54L, 49L, 63L, 73L, 77L, 79L, 
84L, 74L, 68L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 57L, 88L, 71L, 61L, 55L, 75L, 75L, 
57L, 47L, 59L, 74L, 70L, 68L, 69L, 52L, 69L, 65L, 77L, 52L, 65L, 
37L, 66L, 60L, 57L, 79L, 66L, 62L, 72L, 42L, 66L, 44L, 52L, 63L, 
72L, 44L, 78L, 72L, 91L, 59L, 59L, 53L, 51L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 
70L, 64L, 54L, 71L, 58L, 71L, 67L, 76L, 54L, 53L, 81L, 61L, 90L, 
85L, 63L, 40L, 50L, 78L, 48L, 43L, 51L, 50L, 67L, 68L, 57L, 57L, 
57L, 50L, 71L, 81L, 82L, 88L, 81L, 96L, 100L, 78L, 57L, 71L, 
72L, 104L, 89L, 88L, 52L, 59L, 76L, 86L, 111L, 78L, 102L, 105L, 
51L, 59L, 53L, 125L, 140L, 106L, 129L, 116L, 40L, 54L, 73L, 52L, 
82L, 84L, 75L, 73L, 95L, 89L, 100L, 104L, 117L, 79L, 48L, 43L, 
89L, 78L, 69L, 62L, 108L, 83L, 85L, 97L, 88L, 59L, 88L, 66L, 
88L, 97L, 95L, 103L, 110L, 101L, 85L, 94L, 73L, 71L, 79L, 76L, 
52L, 88L, 90L, 101L, 117L, 122L, 117L, 104L, 89L, 108L, 94L, 
102L, 113L, 78L, 88L, 94L, 85L, 105L, 136L, 131L, 143L, 131L, 
127L, 52L, 76L, 58L, 68L, 88L, 79L, 89L, 82L, 76L, 99L, 58L, 
89L, 89L, 68L, 84L, 95L, 45L, 43L, 107L, 122L, 40L, 75L, 74L, 
73L, 82L, 69L, 67L, 65L, 51L, 75L, 73L, 73L, 76L, 56L, 68L, 81L, 
65L, 70L, 55L, 84L, 90L, 89L, 65L, 76L, 82L, 96L, 58L, 38L, 47L, 
94L, 100L, 106L, 114L, 87L, 70L, 70L, 83L, 61L, 84L, 89L, 72L, 
87L, 111L, 113L, 98L, 102L, 67L, 93L, 128L, 102L, 89L, 57L, 75L, 
67L, 89L, 93L, 77L, 59L, 91L, 89L, 76L, 70L, 50L, 85L, 100L, 
102L, 100L, 95L, 99L, 114L, 114L, 116L, 109L, 95L, 105L, 104L, 
100L, 91L, 116L, 92L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 134L, 100L, 106L, 112L, 
87L, 99L, 104L, 112L, 97L, 105L, 85L, 92L, 85L, 75L, 98L, 59L, 
80L, 66L, 83L, 79L, 80L, 86L, 97L, 91L, 75L, 95L, 109L, 72L, 
71L, 78L, 79L, 105L), Max = c(255L, 124L, 117L, 140L, 123L, 124L, 
167L, 157L, 149L, 152L, 145L, 137L, 129L, 180L, 157L, 117L, 129L, 
110L, 248L, 157L, 162L, 161L, 173L, 158L, 129L, 140L, 157L, 144L, 
189L, 122L, 133L, 98L, 178L, 159L, 131L, 127L, 140L, 110L, 139L, 
159L, 174L, 153L, 148L, 110L, 114L, 141L, 157L, 142L, 162L, 187L, 
179L, 122L, 133L, 161L, 160L, 136L, 133L, 114L, 120L, 137L, 126L, 
142L, 114L, 128L, 116L, 137L, 123L, 147L, 150L, 131L, 142L, 126L, 
144L, 103L, 125L, 185L, 173L, 133L, 157L, 152L, 141L, 178L, 153L, 
130L, 142L, 154L, 146L, 143L, 154L, 118L, 202L, 131L, 131L, 125L, 
134L, 127L, 115L, 119L, 120L, 193L, 203L, 209L, 173L, 250L, 184L, 
183L, 204L, 174L, 217L, 180L, 187L, 149L, 144L, 216L, 192L, 161L, 
132L, 229L, 152L, 163L, 125L, 155L, 127L, 153L, 129L, 152L, 172L, 
223L, 163L, 166L, 202L, 148L, 212L, 162L, 175L, 197L, 124L, 156L, 
148L, 126L, 230L, 146L, 192L, 167L, 152L, 129L, 163L, 189L, 148L, 
194L, 201L, 195L, 195L, 152L, 188L, 186L, 242L, 162L, 224L, 186L, 
255L, 195L, 161L, 227L, 210L, 210L, 198L, 214L, 248L, 180L, 238L, 
245L, 200L, 205L, 252L, 179L, 139L, 189L, 197L, 177L, 252L, 202L, 
150L, 163L, 201L, 204L, 151L, 133L, 133L, 154L, 125L, 178L, 129L, 
124L, 152L, 117L, 144L, 166L, 149L, 154L, 173L, 152L, 201L, 161L, 
134L, 235L, 175L, 138L, 183L, 152L, 141L, 111L, 172L, 171L, 190L, 
173L, 182L, 202L, 159L, 199L, 234L, 169L, 166L, 218L, 154L, 146L, 
142L, 153L, 180L, 156L, 137L, 149L, 108L, 217L, 159L, 171L, 169L, 
181L, 186L, 154L, 193L, 222L, 209L, 144L, 198L, 185L, 226L, 243L, 
197L, 138L, 189L, 153L, 255L, 162L, 221L, 170L, 184L, 178L, 180L, 
197L, 185L, 194L, 182L, 151L, 197L, 158L, 115L, 143L, 167L, 176L, 
164L, 193L, 196L, 198L, 141L, 117L, 140L, 124L, 138L, 144L, 217L, 
225L, 159L, 153L, 200L, 241L, 166L, 136L, 254L, 186L, 148L, 190L, 
173L, 145L, 183L, 155L, 119L, 112L, 81L, 86L, 59L, 68L, 50L, 
80L, 74L, 95L, 71L, 67L, 108L, 126L, 130L, 141L, 145L, 123L, 
177L, 168L, 195L, 193L, 204L, 179L, 209L, 190L, 169L, 201L, 171L, 
143L, 130L, 133L, 142L, 139L, 210L, 161L, 118L, 104L, 137L, 134L, 
253L, 185L, 165L, 161L, 180L, 212L, 194L, 186L, 156L, 122L, 126L, 
218L, 204L, 255L, 204L, 169L, 207L, 161L, 157L, 143L, 170L, 196L, 
154L, 140L, 174L, 158L, 192L, 138L, 142L, 210L, 171L, 133L, 166L, 
148L, 158L, 127L, 196L, 160L, 178L, 140L, 153L, 186L, 122L, 150L, 
188L, 242L, 252L, 156L, 183L, 190L, 222L, 194L, 248L, 183L, 237L, 
193L, 255L, 171L, 234L, 205L, 255L, 192L, 196L, 245L, 217L, 131L, 
157L, 192L, 181L, 201L, 228L, 146L, 155L, 217L, 217L, 156L, 169L, 
151L, 138L, 155L, 158L, 174L, 199L, 193L, 185L, 181L, 195L, 179L, 
218L, 208L, 177L, 240L, 210L, 210L, 167L, 171L, 192L, 196L, 205L, 
203L, 183L, 191L, 224L, 177L, 209L, 128L, 195L, 130L, 87L, 142L, 
175L, 202L, 144L, 221L, 243L, 190L, 144L, 134L, 167L, 173L, 254L, 
189L, 225L, 232L, 245L, 234L, 209L, 187L, 139L, 214L, 237L, 162L, 
163L, 218L, 171L, 184L, 241L, 220L, 242L, 175L, 231L, 190L, 194L, 
169L, 172L, 93L, 135L, 225L, 203L, 167L, 169L, 167L, 163L, 219L, 
184L, 183L, 242L, 193L, 160L, 201L, 245L, 157L, 179L, 186L, 203L, 
193L, 135L, 178L, 181L, 142L, 255L, 168L, 137L, 128L, 94L, 143L, 
117L, 184L, 138L, 175L, 150L, 128L, 186L, 177L, 226L, 229L, 206L, 
171L, 225L, 240L, 157L, 130L, 224L, 203L, 209L, 240L, 152L, 247L, 
205L, 161L, 235L, 188L, 183L, 218L, 249L, 206L, 185L, 235L, 204L, 
227L, 203L, 200L, 90L, 115L, 174L, 159L, 159L, 123L, 141L, 154L, 
137L, 129L, 135L, 122L, 207L, 121L, 112L, 152L, 159L, 135L, 134L, 
181L, 117L, 149L, 166L, 172L, 87L, 111L, 128L, 137L, 152L, 117L, 
125L, 145L, 145L, 152L, 190L, 106L, 97L, 154L, 150L, 123L, 133L, 
121L, 178L, 156L, 127L, 159L, 125L, 112L, 118L, 129L, 146L, 121L, 
109L, 168L, 108L, 110L, 82L, 147L, 158L, 111L, 111L, 124L, 124L, 
155L, 154L, 113L, 143L, 153L, 124L, 115L, 135L, 124L, 134L, 139L, 
141L, 169L, 193L, 115L, 127L, 167L, 173L, 134L, 176L, 136L, 141L, 
145L, 193L, 140L, 255L, 141L, 132L, 155L, 150L, 195L, 145L, 175L, 
174L, 244L, 156L, 136L, 140L, 179L, 193L, 176L, 255L, 171L, 141L, 
160L, 142L, 154L, 166L, 174L, 110L, 123L, 78L, 223L, 233L, 223L, 
216L, 189L, 148L, 198L, 185L, 148L, 186L, 174L, 205L, 137L, 141L, 
186L, 129L, 156L, 186L, 133L, 137L, 146L, 167L, 231L, 197L, 191L, 
162L, 184L, 143L, 190L, 153L, 161L, 158L, 134L, 148L, 151L, 145L, 
166L, 170L, 164L, 123L, 154L, 133L, 157L, 138L, 159L, 172L, 166L, 
236L, 255L, 193L, 215L, 180L, 191L, 165L, 209L, 241L, 188L, 151L, 
167L, 174L, 162L, 116L, 185L, 213L, 228L, 250L, 236L, 184L, 222L, 
164L, 177L, 127L, 190L, 209L, 255L, 163L, 173L, 151L, 221L, 167L, 
190L, 190L, 207L, 214L, 114L, 74L, 199L, 185L, 162L, 125L, 135L, 
161L, 132L, 122L, 140L, 123L, 125L, 133L, 127L, 116L, 119L, 164L, 
119L, 123L, 123L, 110L, 119L, 188L, 173L, 132L, 136L, 142L, 202L, 
250L, 133L, 117L, 97L, 146L, 159L, 172L, 184L, 153L, 134L, 255L, 
127L, 130L, 134L, 133L, 143L, 189L, 171L, 181L, 184L, 183L, 132L, 
147L, 163L, 199L, 188L, 164L, 130L, 155L, 192L, 182L, 131L, 168L, 
133L, 146L, 147L, 192L, 97L, 159L, 160L, 189L, 148L, 167L, 140L, 
204L, 144L, 150L, 194L, 142L, 171L, 148L, 151L, 167L, 207L, 176L, 
203L, 167L, 193L, 254L, 181L, 188L, 213L, 178L, 194L, 198L, 173L, 
145L, 162L, 151L, 153L, 179L, 140L, 220L, 176L, 230L, 124L, 211L, 
189L, 136L, 166L, 182L, 165L, 151L, 176L, 223L, 150L, 154L, 129L, 
145L, 164L)), .Names = c("Area", "Mean", "Min", "Max"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-866L))
```